# Track logins made via non-interactive shells

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, login

This is in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079275/tracking-ansible-logins/45079757#45079757).

I wanted to log everytime someone logged in via ansible.

I put my script in `~/.bash_profile` file. Here is the script,

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date +"%T")
echo "$USER logged in at: $now" >> /home/alphauser/ssh-entries.log
```

I put this at the end of `~/.bash_profile`,

```
bash ~/ssh-login-entry.sh
```

However, ansible uses the non-interactive shell, so my script was not executed when I logged in via ansible as `~/.bash_profile` is executed only when a new interactive shell is started.

Then I pasted this at the end of `.bashrc` file, but still it did not work.

How can I log entries when someone logs in via non-interactive shell ?
I mean where should I place this script so that it should be executed everytime someone logs in via ansible ?

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: bash_profile is for login-non-interactive shells. use `~/.bashrc` for non-login shells

Comment: yes that is what I know. please check my edit

Comment: try to delete bash_profile and bash_login and put it in .profile

Comment: how will that help ?

Comment: .profile is the same thing. if not, then try to put `export TEST='testing'`,then try and see if test variable is set

Comment: no, even that is not being set.

Comment: Don't use `.bash_profile` at all. In Ubuntu we use `.profile` and it's not executed if `.bash_profile` exists. Maybe this is responsible for other strange things happening on your system

Comment: @Zanna I firstly tried that in `.profile`, but it was not working there, it was nt even logging simple ssh logins. So, I put it in `.bash_profile`. There it logged ssh logins but not ansible logins.

Comment: Regardless, it may well cause problems. If you insist on using `.bash_profile`, then I suggest you at least copy the code from `.profile` into it. But I don't know if that will prevent all possible issues...

Comment: Is the system `auth.log` file (in `/var/log`) not useful for this?

Comment: Yes indeed. But that has a lot of other information also. And it also has info about ssh logins and all other kinds of logins. So, I was trying to get a separate file for the non-interactive logins.

Comment: This is on topic here, why do you want to migrate it to [linux.se]?

Comment: @Zanna there's no reason not to use `.bash_profile`, it's just not relevant here because the OP is running a non-interactive shell. Basically, if `.bash_profile` exists, then `.profile` is ignored by `bash`. But that's no reason not to use it. Especially if you want to have separate settings for different shells (`~/.bash_profile` is only read by `bash` while `~/.profile` is read by most or all login shells).

Comment: @terdon I guess I should assume people know what they are doing when they're asking about something else

Comment: @terdon yes this is on topic but as I was not getting answer here, I tried to migrate it hoping that I may get an answer there.

Comment: It's only been a day! We try not to migrate away questions that are on topic. I can, if you insist (or you could always just delete and repost there), but why not give it a bit more time? That said, I expect there's more ansible expertise at U&L, yes. Still, if you decide to move it, I suggest you just delete this and repost there. That way, the question will appear as new and more people will see it. Neither of the answers you've received here seem to be what you need, so deleting is no great loss.

Answer (score 1):

When bash is started as a non-interactive shell, it doesn't read any startup files. Instead, it looks for the environment variable `$BASH_ENV` and, if that points to a file, reads whatever it points to. This is explained in the INVOCATION section of `man bash`:

> When bash is started non-interactively, to  run  a  shell  script, 
>   for    example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment,
>   expands    its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value
>   as the  name    of  a  file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if
>   the following com‐    mand were executed:
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value 
>   of the PATH variable is not used to search for the  file‐
>   name.

So, if you set `BASH_ENV` to point to a file containing your command, it should work:

1. Edit `/etc/environment` to set `BASH_ENV` for all users. Open the file in your favorite editor and add this line:

   ```
   export BASH_ENV="/path/to/your/file"
   ```
2. Create `/path/to/your/file` with the following contents:

   ```
   printf '%s logged in at: %s\n' "$USER" "$(date +'%T')" >> /home/alphauser/ssh-entries.log
   ```

Now try logging in via ansible again.

**Important**: I have no experience with ansible, so I am not entirely sure how you log in using it. This assumes that you first start a normal login shell and then run the ansible command. If not, it will probably fail. If this doesn't work, please edit your question and give more information about how you log in through ansible.

Comment: One thing is for sure, ansible uses non-interactive shell. I did as you said. But it did not work. However, After running ansible playbook, I login via ssh and then ran `echo $BASH_ENV` and it returned nothing.

Comment: @luv.preet no, ssh is another special case. What does ssh have to do with it? You don't mention it in your question.

Comment: Nothing to do with ssh. But it should echo out the name of the variable when I run `echo $BASH_ENV`, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @luv.preet yes, but only if you single quote it to protect from the current shell: `ssh user@host echo '$BASH_ENV'`.

Answer (score 0):

All log-ins, interactive and non-interactive, local and remote are logged to `/var/log/auth.log`. I suggest you use that instead of messing with profile start-up files that the audited user account can modify.

Comment: Thanks david. I knew this, but I just needed a separate file for ansible logins.

Comment: Can't you filter the log file for specific log-in types? I don't use Ansible myself. Maybe you can provide a log file excerpt after an Ansible log in and I can help you how to distinguish it from other log entries.